# 'Sounds' folder not loading correctly to localhost

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

Good afternoon,
I've been following [this](http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-game-tutorial-game-ui-canvas-vs-dom/) tutorial to make a simple (!) html5 canvas game. I've been using the error console on Safari to help troubleshoot, but I can't figure this one out; I have an 'img' folder, containing all artwork, and a 'sounds' folder, containing all sounds.
All assets are loaded with the assetLoader and checked before the page loads - if something is missing or labelled incorrectly, it won't load.
The sounds 'do' play - the theme music runs fine, and sound effects trigger approx 60% - 70% of the time (jump sound, collide sound etc) but the folder hasn't loaded correctly. If I check the 'resources' tab, 'sounds' is now called 'Other', and if I click on any of the mp3's in that folder, I get the message 'An error occurred trying to load the resource'.
The assetLoader part of the code looks like this:

```
var assetLoader = (function() {

 this.sounds      = {
 'bg'            : 'sounds/theme.mp3',
 'jump'          : 'sounds/fart.mp3',
 'gameOver'      : 'sounds/gameOver.mp3',
 'ding'         : 'sounds/ding.mp3'
 };
```

Then I have a var to check the total number of sound assets:

```
var numSounds    = Object.keys(this.sounds).length;
```

Then I have this function to check the state:

```
 function _checkAudioState(sound) {
if (this.sounds[sound].status === 'loading' && this.sounds[sound].readyState === 4) 
  { assetLoaded.call(this, 'sounds', sound);
 }
}
```

Finally, I have a downloadAll function that looks like this:

```
this.downloadAll = function() {
var _this = this;
var src;


for (var img in this.imgs) {
  if (this.imgs.hasOwnProperty(img)) {
    src = this.imgs[img];


    (function(_this, img) {
      _this.imgs[img] = new Image();
      _this.imgs[img].status = 'loading';
      _this.imgs[img].name = img;
      _this.imgs[img].onload = function() { assetLoaded.call(_this,  'imgs', img) };
      _this.imgs[img].src = src;
       })(_this, img);
      }
     }


  for (var sound in this.sounds) {
  if (this.sounds.hasOwnProperty(sound)) {
    src = this.sounds[sound];

    (function(_this, sound) {
      _this.sounds[sound] = new Audio();
      _this.sounds[sound].status = 'loading';
      _this.sounds[sound].name = sound;
      _this.sounds[sound].addEventListener('canplay', function() {
        _checkAudioState.call(_this, sound);
      });
      _this.sounds[sound].src = src;
      _this.sounds[sound].preload = 'auto';
      _this.sounds[sound].load();
     })(_this, sound);
    }
   }
  }

 return {
 imgs: this.imgs,
 sounds: this.sounds,
 totalAssest: this.totalAssest,
 downloadAll: this.downloadAll
  };
 })();
```

I've left the images in this block of code as they work fine, and I think the sounds should too, but for some reason they don't. I have read about potential mp3 compatibility problems with browsers and html5 canvas, but as the sounds are playing I'm not sure this is the issue. If anyone can offer any insight, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this javascript file in the same folder as your HTML, or in a specific folder named `js/` ?

Comment: Hi @Roberrrt, within the parent folder I have the index.html, .js and .css sheets as well as the 'img' folder and the 'sounds' folder, which contain the assets. I've tried to change the path to include the parent folder but that didn't work. The images load to localhost and show up in the console, but the sounds, which are in the same place but their own folder, don't.